# Saving Model in Mongoose fails to save nested component

Tags: mongoose, nosql

I have the following model schema:

```
var memberSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    'project'       : { 
        'type'      : Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        'ref'       : 'Project' 
    },
    'first'         : String,
    'last'          : String,
    'email'         : String,
    'tracker'       : {
        'etag'      : String,
        'id'        : String,
        'photoLink' : String,
        'role'      : String,
        'type'      : String,
                      },
    'survey'        : {
        'etag'      : String,
        'id'        : String,
        'photoLink' : String,
        'role'      : String,
        'type'      : String,
                      },

});
```

I want to save a new document. I perform the following:

```
var Member     = require('../app/models/member');

var new_member = new Member({
  project      : project._id,
  first        : req.body.all_perms[i].first,
  last         : req.body.all_perms[i].last,
  email        : req.body.all_perms[i].email,
  tracker      : {
                    etag      : req.body.all_perms[i].etag_tracker,
                    id        : req.body.all_perms[i].ftid_tracker,
                    photoLink : req.body.all_perms[i].photoLink_tracker,
                    role      : req.body.all_perms[i].role_tracker,
                    type      : req.body.all_perms[i].type_tracker,
                 },
  survey       : {
                    etag      : req.body.all_perms[i].etag_survey,
                    id        : req.body.all_perms[i].ftid_survey,
                    photoLink : req.body.all_perms[i].photoLink_survey,
                    role      : req.body.all_perms[i].role_survey,
                    type      : req.body.all_perms[i].type_survey,
                 },
})
new_member.save(function(err, saved_result) {})
```

Performing this operation results in a successfully created new document BUT the document does not contain either `tracker` or `survey`. It does, however, contain `first`, `last`, and `email`.

How do I successfully save the nested component of the new model? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a field in an embedded object named `type`, you need to use the object notation to define its type or Mongoose thinks it's defining the type of the parent object.

So change your schema to:

```js
var memberSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    'project'       : { 
        'type'      : Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        'ref'       : 'Project' 
    },
    'first'         : String,
    'last'          : String,
    'email'         : String,
    'tracker'       : {
        'etag'      : String,
        'id'        : String,
        'photoLink' : String,
        'role'      : String,
        'type'      : {'type': String},   // Here...
    },
    'survey'        : {
        'etag'      : String,
        'id'        : String,
        'photoLink' : String,
        'role'      : String,
        'type'      : {'type': String},   // ...and here
    },
});
```